# Playing sound in internet explorer mobile 6

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-phone

we have a web application which is targeted to work on Internet Mobile Explorer 6. We need to play a sound when the user inputs an incorrect ... "input". Any idea what is supported on ie mobile 6 and how I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? Does flash work? Does it play mp3? Does it support `<audio>`?

Comment: Web apps don't typically play sounds when validation fails, and I think we should keep it that way.

Comment: I have tried <embed> which doesn't work and using the yahoo player which of course was an overkill

Comment: @jrummell hehe go tell that to our client

Comment: @Jonny I'm sorry to hear that. You may be able to `<embed>` a wmv file or something.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is somewhat old, but I think it still deserves an answer. This is how I got it working. If you are only targeting IE6 Mobile, you could so something like the following in your head tag:

```
<bgsound id="bgSoundId" loop="0" volume="100" />
```

And then have a JavaScript function like so:

```
function playSound() {
    document.getElementById("bgSoundId").src = "path/to/file.wav";
}
```

So, then you just call that function from your validation logic.

Comment: Yes!  This works.  Also, the audio file *must* be a WAV file.  IE6 Mobile does not appear to support MP3 or MIDI.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<bgsound>` in `<embed>` in `<audio>` (to support as much browser, as you could)

```
<audio src="sound.url" type="mime/type">
  <embed src="sound.url" type="mime/type">
    <bgsound src="sound.url">
    </bgsound>
  </embed>
</audio>
```

But `embed` & `bgsound` has no generic way to start playing from javascript, as far as i can tell.

Comment: so ie mobile 6 has some additional limitations above ie6's, great :S - then i don't think it's possible without a plugin.