# Play sound file on Windows Mobile .NET or CE Internet Explorer with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, windows-mobile

I need to play some wav or any sound file on Windows Mobile .CE or Windows Mobile .NET device in its default browser (Internet explorer). The devices browser has very limited javascript capabilities. I tried the following without result:

```
<embed src="test.wav"..
..
var audio = new Audio("test.wav")
..
<audio src="test.wav"..
..
var e = document.createElement('audio'); a.innerHTML = '<source src="test.wav" type="audio/wav"..
..
<BGSOUND ID="BGSOUND_ID" LOOP=1 VOLUME="600" SRC="test.mid">
```

Comment: How you checked the solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12809156/4606266

Comment: Yes, but the capabiltiy is below IE 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running windows mobile 5 or better or Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5, he following will work:

```
<!--<span class="code-comment"> <bgsound src="file://’windows’asterisk.wav" loop="infinite"> --></span>
<!--<span class="code-comment"> use refresh to return to page --></span>
    <object type="audio/x-wav" 
data="file://’windows’asterisk.wav" width="1" height="1">
    <param name="FileName" value="file://’windows’asterisk.wav">
    <param name="hidden" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="false">
    <param name="numloop" value="2">
    </object>
<noembed> <p>Could not embed wav file!</p> </noembed>
<embed src="file://’windows’asterisk.wav" width="1" height="1" 
hidden="true" type="audio/x-wav">
<a href="javascript:document.embeds[0].play()">Starten</a>
```

You may find two different Browser Engines, one more or less comaptible to IE5 and one compatible to IE6.

See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61647/The-Pocket-or-Mobile-Internet-Explorer